# buscar un elemento en un un resultado de una tabla

Tags: laravel

Estoy  Estoy haciendo un pequeño módulo de entrega de tareas.
Entonces, Cuando hago la consulta que pertencen a un grupo.

Me muestra todos los usuarios que hicieron dicha entrega,

de  esta manera cargo todas las tareas, con sus entregas, en dicha entrega viene el ID del  usuario que entrego, Podría agregarle . user, pero no ya no es necesario pues viene ya el Id-user en la entrega.

```html
 $tareas = $sala->load('tareas.entregas','users');
```

Entonces, en donde dice USERS. Cargo todos los usuarios que pertenecen a esta sala.

en este ejemplo.

```
  si hay 30 usuarios y 20 tareas. Sabiendo que solo algunos no entregaron todas entonces,
```

Podría decir que lo recorrería con un foreach. pero viene siendo muy largo,
Ya que .

Debería de comparar. `Toda la lista de usuarios` cada uno. si cumplió la primera tarea.

Entonces viene siendo `600`  **Repeticiones**

entonces la duda surge si hay algo mejor.

así es como esta la lista de tareas. aquí solo puse una, Pero habrá más con sus respectivas entregas.

donde dice entregas viene el user-id

```html
"tareas": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "titulo": "alaalejayeeee actualizando",
      "descripcion": "<p>....</p>",
      "sala_id": 1,
      "entregar_at": "2018-12-12 03:19:21",
      "created_at": "2018-12-12 00:08:44",
      "updated_at": "2018-12-12 01:28:13",
      "entregas": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "descripcion": "ddgfkdgfklñdfgkñldfgklñfdgñlfdgfggfdgfdgfdgf",
          "cal": 87,
          "tarea_id": 5,
          "user_id": 4,
          "created_at": "2018-12-19 11:12:54",
          "updated_at": "2018-12-19 12:09:47"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "descripcion": "lmdfsdkfkjdfdkll",
          "cal": 89,
          "tarea_id": 5,
          "user_id": 2,
          "created_at": "2013-12-19 12:38:12",
          "updated_at": "2018-12-19 12:39:02"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Entonces hay una forma más directa de comprobar ya que voy a llenarlo en una tabla, entonces necesito.

saber si el primer usuario de la lista de usuarios se encuentra en la lista de entregas de la primer tarea.

No sé, buscandolo dentro, como se hace con los arrays. buscar un elemento en particular y si existe entonces  hacemos algo.

Comment: ¿qué es lo que necesita buscar exactamente?